# Azure App Services: How can a WebJob send a response to WebAPI?

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-web-app-service

In Azure, I have a **WebAPI** and a **WebJob**. WebAPI sends messages to an **Azure Service Bus** queue, and the WebJob is the only **subscriber** of that queue. When the WebJob finalizes a processing job, how can it then pass a response message to the WebAPI?

Answer (score 1):

You could create an API to accept the response from WebJob. Code below is for your reference.

```
public class WebJobResponseController : ApiController
{
    public string Get(string token, string value)
    {
        //use the token to validate the webjob, use the value to post any data which you want to send to API
        return "success";
    }
}
```

On your WebJob side, after processed the job, you just need to send a request to the upper API. Code below is for your reference.

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("URL of your API");
await client.GetAsync("WebJobResponse?token=token1&value=value1");
```

Comment: Any update? If you have further questions related to this topic, please feel free to let me know.